# Merge two DF in one pandas DF

Tags: pandas

I am trying to merge two dataframe in one:
[SNIPPET](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ms7hW.png)

I want one DF as:

```
184 5(sum of both)
108 1(from first DF)
271 2(from second DF)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
df1.add(df2, fill_value=0)
```

Or:

```
pd.concat([df1, df2]).sum(level=0)
```